# Referencing one model from another model in node.js

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two models Question and Answer. A Question has many Answers, and an Answer belongs to a Question.

Then in Loopback provides a reference to an Answer. What I can't figure out is how do I then get a reference to the Question that the Answer belongs to!?

```
module.exports = function(Answer) {

    console.log(ctx.instance.question)
    console.log(ctx.instance.question.points) // undefined


};
```

I can get what looks like a reference to the object ... but I don't know how to reference any properties on that object!?

How do I reference a model that belongsto another model?

Question and Answer provided below for reference.

```
{
  "name": "Question",
  "plural": "Questions",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "text": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "points": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "answers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Answer",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "approval": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Approval",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "student": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Student",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}

{
  "name": "Answer",
  "plural": "Answers",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "text": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "question": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Question",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "student": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Student",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "approval": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Approval",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the code you provided is from your `common/model/answer.js` file based on what it looks like, but that file is executed during application set up. The context (`ctx` in your sample) would not exist there. Context is only given during a [remote hook](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+hooks) or other such action. As such, I'll give you an answer based on a hook for finding an `Answer` by its ID and then getting the related question. This code should go in your `common/model/answer.js` file (inside the exported wrapper function):

```
Answer.afterRemote('findById', function(ctx, theAnswer, next) {
  theAnswer.question(function(err, question) { // this is an async DB call
    if (err) { return next(err); } // this would be bad...
    console.log(question);

    // You can then alter the question if necessary...
    question.viewCount++
    question.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        // an error here might be bad... maybe handle it better...
        return next(err);
      }
      // if get here things are good, so call next() to move on.
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Note that if you wanted to do this during some other step in the request-response cycle it might be different. You would hit this remote hook any time a call to `/api/Answers/[id]` is hit.

Seconde note: you can also get this data straight from the API if you just need it on the client:

`.../api/Answers?filter={"include":"question"}`

**[Updated to show saving a question.]**

Comment: Ahhh ... that is awesome! Very related question ... that I didn't realize would be different from above. I don't seem to be able to make change to question. For example, if I say    ctx.instance.student(function (err, student) {
      student.points = student.points - question.points
    }) question isn't actually changed when returning from this call. Is there another call to make changes to question? I am  calling this from Question.observe('after save')

Comment: If instead I call ctx.instance.student(function (err, student) { student.updateAttributes({points: student.points - points}, (err, instance) => {}) } that works. Please confirm that this is the right idiom.

Comment: You would need to `save()` your question instance in order for any changes to persist.

Comment: Got it! Such a noob request ... but could you please augment the example above to demonstrate how a property on question would be changed. It isn't obvious to me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation page](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/defining-and-mapping-data-relations-with-loopback-connected-models/) (see the very beginning of "Methods added to the model for belongsTo" section) you are looking for Answer.prototype.question() method. Perhaps it needs to be lowercase in your sample?

Comment: Thanks! When I do that ... I get the following error: 

Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
C:\devel\nodejs\athena\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\relation-def
inition.js:289
  return this.modelInstance.__cachedRelations[this.definition.name];
                                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined
    at BelongsTo.Relation.getCache

Comment: Printing out to the console Answer.prototype shows that "ModelConstructor", with what looks like it has the properties I need, but I don't know how to access them. ModelConstructor {

  text: [Getter/Setter],

  id: [Getter/Setter],

  save: [Function],

  questionId: [Getter/Setter],

  question: [Getter],

  __get__question: [Function],

}

Comment: You have to synchronize your model and database schema. Try autoupdate. https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+a+database+schema+from+models#Creatingadatabaseschemafrommodels-Auto-update

Comment: From that documentation ... autoupdate applies only to database connectors but I am using the memory connector {
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory",
    "file": "database.json"
  }
}